# В чём разница между *this и this?

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, теория, this

Я никак не могу понять в чём между ними разница. `this` - указатель на объект, `*this` - ссылка на объект. Если `*this` - разыменование указателя, то `*this` возвращает объект.

Объект - это получается ссылка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*this` - по своей сущности не ссылка! Это сам объект. Именно возвращаемое значение определяет каким будет `this`. Смотрите:

```
MyClass foo();
MyClass& foo();
```

Это по-разному можно интерпретировать. Как видите, разыменованый `this` в первом варианте - просто копия объекта, во втором - ссылка на объект класса.

Comment: И как же возвращают ССЫЛКУ перегруженные операторы? Например, class A{puplic: int x; A& operator =(const int &x){this->x=x; return *this;}} возвращает именно ссылку.

Comment: Это: «Как видите, разыменованый this в первом варианте - просто копия объекта, во втором - ссылка на объект класса» значения не имеет. Никто не запрещал, имея ссылку, взять по ней значение и вернуть его. Это даже не привидение без фактического преобразования, это просто адресация объекта по ссылке.

Answer (score 2):

Ссылка хранится в памяти как константный указатель на объект (*Константный подразумевается сам указатель, а не объект.*), но обращение по ссылке автоматически переводятся к этому объекту.  И синтаксис такой-же как к обычному объекту.

```
class C{
public :
  int x ;
};

C o ;  // объект
C * const po = & o ; // константный указатель на объект
C & ps = o ; // ссылка на объект

po -> x = 0 ; // обращение по указателю
ps . x = 0 ; // обращение по ссылке
o . x = 0 ; // к объекту так-же как по ссылке
```

Оператор звёздочка * на указатель преобразует его на ссылку.

`po -> x` === `( * po ) . x` === `ps . x` === `o . x`

```
C &       spo = * po ; // из указателя на ссылку
С * const pps = & ps ; // из ссылки на указатель
```

Для вашего вопроса `this` - это константный указатель на изменяемый объект, а `* this` - это ссылка.

Comment: `Ссылка это то-же самое, что константный указатель на объект`, т.е в вашем примере гарантированно `sizeof(po) == sizeof(ps)`? Ведь константный указатель `po` это тоже самое, что ссылка `ps`, просто другой синтаксис?

Comment: Нет, язык автоматически ссылку подразумевает как объект. `sizeof(po)` - это размер указателя, а `sizeof(ps)` - размер объекта. @wololo

Comment: `а звёздочка на ссылку возвращают то-же самое (ссылку на объект) ... C & ps = o ; C & sps = * ps ;` Это не скомпилируется.

Comment: понял, значит перепутал с автоматическим приведением типов. @wololo

Answer (score 0):

Да, *this – это ссылка на себя, а просто this – указатель. У них разные синтаксисы и разные возможности. Например, получив объект по ссылке, вызывающий код не может даже попытаться, не приводя ссылку к указателю, освободить память, занятую объектом, на который указывает this. Если же вернуть this, то сама попытка возможна. Защитит ли система объект от удаления – вопрос отдельный.

```
class A
{
 public:
  int x;
 A& f1 =(const int &x)
 {
  this->x=x;
  return *this;  
 }
 A* f2 =(const int &x)
 {
  this->x=x;
  return this;  
 }
};
int main()
{
 A *p1;
 A *p2;
 p1=new A;
 p2=new A;
 delete p1->f1(2); // Синтаксическая ошибка, объект по указателю p1 защищён, несмотря на размещение в куче
 delete p2->f2(2); // Объект по указателю p2 будет удалён, а занимаемая им память – освобождена
return 0;
}
```